# tfs 2010 on vista ultimate

Tags: tfs

i was able to install tfs 2010 on window server 2008 and through team explorer in visual studio 2010  the server came right up no problems. However when i installed it on vista ultimate - first the options were slightly different to install but the wizards worked fine but when i tried to access the url on team explore in visual studio 2010 -   i constantly get
500 error.  I also noticed the window server 2008 hat "nt authority\network service" which
tfs uses, however window vista sp2 only has "nt authority\local service".  (i even tried
to simulate this account on vista in a similar fashion as window server 2008 but to no avail)

Please help.  p.s.  this is on x86 version of the software.

HELP, HELP, HELP.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search turned up [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfssetup/thread/049eab2e-025f-40e9-a74f-33d02c763d25), where someone was having a similar issue.